# Setting cells from selected range as formula inputs

Tags: vba, excel, range, formula

I've created a simple CAGR formula which allows me to calculate CAGR based on given inputs - first period, last period and number of periods).

Now, I'd like to be able to run the formula on a selected range of cells. I cannot think of any fancy and simple ways to do it. The macro itself should be able to recognize the leftmost cell of the range as the first period, rightmost as the last one and count the number of cells to come up with the number of periods.

Could you please help me out?

My CAGR formula macro looks like this:

```
Public Function CAGR(First, Last, Periods)

    CAGR = ((Last / First) ^ (1 / Periods)) - 1

End Function
```

Thanks in advance.
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You can access the currently selected range like so :

```
Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.range(Application.Selection.Address)
```

I'll leave the rest up to you, but if you get stuck post a comment and I'll give some more guidance :)

Comment: Actually, that's probably an overcomplicated solution. I think you can do everything you need with just Application.Selection.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need a input range which can be one row wide or one column high (see the checking part). Then the calculation is a bit different for row or column mode (see the comments in the code).

1. You can use that function from any Excel cell like …

   - `=CAGR(A1:F1)` input is row mode
   - `=CAGR(A1:A6)` input is column mode
   - `=CAGR(A1:B5)` this input is invalid because `row.count` and `column.count` is `>1` this will return a error: `#REF!`
2. Or from VBA like …

   ```
   Public Sub MsgCagrOfSelection()
       MsgBox CAGR(Selection) 'MessageBox the CARG result of the current selected cells
   End Sub
   ```

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CAGR(rngInput As Range) As Variant 'needs to be variant so we can return errors too

    ' first we do some checking
    ' input range has to be one column or one row only
    If rngInput.Columns.Count > 1 And rngInput.Rows.Count > 1 Then
        CAGR = CVErr(xlErrRef)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim First As Double
    Dim Last As Double
    Dim Periods As Long

    ' calculation is a bit different if we have a column or row as input range
    If rngInput.Columns.Count > 1 Then ' we have one row
        First = rngInput.Resize(1, 1).Value
        Last = rngInput.Resize(1, 1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=rngInput.Columns.Count - 1).Value
        Periods = rngInput.Columns.Count
    Else ' we have one column
        First = rngInput.Resize(1, 1).Value
        Last = rngInput.Resize(1, 1).Offset(RowOffset:=rngInput.Rows.Count - 1).Value
        Periods = rngInput.Rows.Count
    End If

    ' first value has not to be 0 we can't divide by 0
    If First = 0 Then
        CAGR = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
        Exit Function
    End If

    CAGR = ((Last / First) ^ (1 / Periods)) - 1
End Function
```